# No definition found for class:'com.saehyun.mcss.ui.SearchViewModel'. Check your definitions! Error

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, runtime-error, koin

Im trying to implement a Permission Injection using Koin as my D.I However, an error occurs when executing the view model.

> 2021-11-23 18:50:20.144 9408-9408/com.saehyun.mcss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.saehyun.mcss, PID: 9408
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.saehyun.mcss/com.saehyun.mcss.feature.search.ui.SearchActivity}: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.saehyun.mcss.ui.SearchViewModel'. Check your definitions!
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)

this is error code

BaseApplication

```
package com.saehyun.mcss.di

import android.app.Application
import com.saehyun.mcss.di.module.searchModule
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidFileProperties
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidLogger
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module

class McssApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@McssApplication)

            module {
                searchModule
            }

        }
    }
}
```

SearchModule

```
package com.saehyun.mcss.di.module

import com.saehyun.mcss.data.search.SearchRepository
import com.saehyun.mcss.feature.search.viewmodel.SearchViewModel
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.dsl.viewModel
import org.koin.dsl.module

val searchModule = module {
    factory { SearchRepository() }
    viewModel { SearchViewModel(get()) }
}
```

SearchRepository

```
package com.saehyun.mcss.data.search

import com.saehyun.mcss.data.searchApi
import com.saehyun.mcss.feature.search.model.McsrvstatusResponse
import retrofit2.Response

class SearchRepository {

    suspend fun serverInfo(serverIp: String) : Response<McsrvstatusResponse> {
        return searchApi.serverInfo(serverIp)
    }

}
```

SearchViewModel

```
package com.saehyun.mcss.feature.search.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.saehyun.mcss.data.search.SearchRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class SearchViewModel(
    private val repository: SearchRepository
    ) : ViewModel() {

    val toastMessage : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    fun serverInfo(serverId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.serverInfo(serverId)

            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                toastMessage.value = "성공"
            } else {
                toastMessage.value = "실패"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `jcenter()` repository in your `settings.gradle` file and then sync the project. Like this,

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```